# filter text file using script

Tags: python, perl

I have a tab-delimited text file that is very large. Some lines have the same value in the file, some lines just have unique value, For example:

```
a   foo
a   bar
a   foo2
b   bar2
c   bar2
c   foo3
d   bar3
...
```

I also have another ID list file, which is just part of the whole list. For example:

```
a
b
d
...
```

I want to get the correspond value for those ID list, the ID list is unique. How can I do it using perl script or python or basic bash command? Appreciate it!

Comment: Have a look at `grep -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $id_list, '<', 'id_list_file';
my %ids = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } readline $id_list;
close $id_list;

open my $text_file, '<', 'text_file';
while ( my $line = readline $text_file ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($id, $value) = split /\t/, $line, 2;
    if ( $ids{ $id } ) {
        print "got value $value for id $id\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we need close the file after the extraction?

Comment: you don't _need_ to, but why not? It makes it clearer that you will not use it again later in the code.

Comment: Nothing happen when I run your script. Did I missing some arguments?

Comment: Your map looks a bit funky. It appears that you're hash is using the entire line as a key to the value of `1` instead of splitting the line into a key and value, and creating `$ids{$key} = $value`. Am I reading it wrong? Maybe you're correct and I'm just confused. I'm easily confused and easily distracted by shiny objects.

Comment: The "ID list file" as shown only has ids, not ids and values.

Comment: @Jianguo: if you mean the filenames, command line arguments go in @ARGV, so you could pass the two filenames on the command line and replace 'id_list_file' and 'text_file' with `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Quickie untested Python:

```
ids = set()
with open('id-list.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        ids.add(line.strip())
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.strip().split('\t', 1)
        if parts[0] in ids:
            print line,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following code(sure that it should be rewritten(to not create list and dict but just perform some actions on the items found) the usual way especially in case when your files are too big):

```
ids = [row.strip() for row in open('c:\\ids.txt','r') if row.strip()]
data = dict(row.strip().split() for row in open('c:\\data.txt','r') if row.strip())
for id in ids:
    print data.get(id)
```

Sorry, have missed that there could be more than one value for id:

```
output = {}
for row in open('c:\\tst.txt','r'):
    if not row.strip():
        continue
    id, datavalue = row.strip().split()
    if not id in output:
        output[id] = []
    output[id].append(datavalue)
```

Or using [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)
for row in open('c:\\tst.txt','r'):
    if not row.strip():
        continue
    id, datavalue = row.strip().split()
    output[id].append(datavalue)
```

Comment: Why just can print one data using the id list. I also want to print all results with same ID.

Comment: @Jianguo - use 'ids = [row.strip() for row in open('c:\\ids.txt','r') if row.strip()]' from the first sample.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at your *ID* list:

```
a foo
a bar
a foo2
b bar2
c bar2
c foo3
d bar3
```

It appears that `a` can be both `foo` and `bar`. The second column is unique, but not the first column. However, your other list looks like this:

```
a
b
d
```

Which seems to say that the first column (which isn't unique) are the keys. Exactly what should I return when I read `a` in the first list. Do I return both `foo` and `bar`, or was this a mistake?

I need to know this before we can give you an answer.

---

## Addendum

> I need to return both of them. Sorry about the confusion

Okay, in Perl, the easiest way to store key information is to use a *Hash*. The problem with a Hash is that you only have a single value with each key. In your file, that's not the case, you have two separate values with each key. There are two ways of handling this:

### Method #1: Append the value to the previous value

```
open (ID_FILE, "id_file.txt")
    or die qq(Can't open "id_file.txt" for reading\n);
my %idHash;
while (my $line = <ID_FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($key, $value) = split("/s+", $line);
    if (exists $idHash{$key}) {
        $idHash{$key} .= " " . $value;
    }
    else {
        $idHash{$key} = $value;
    }
}
close ID_FILE;
```

In the end of the loop, `$idHash{'a'}` = `foo bar`. Thus, in your second loop:

```
open (ID_LIST, 'list_of_ids.txt')
    or die qq(Can't open "list_of_ids.txt" for reading\n);
while (my $line = <ID_LIST>) {
    chomp $line;
    print qq("$line" keys are "$idHash{$line}"\n);
}
```

### Method #2: Store a List of Hashes

This is dangerous territory. It adds confusion and I usually recommend that you think about object oriented programming when you get into list of hashes or hashes of lists, etc.

```
open (ID_FILE, "id_file.txt")
    or die qq(Can't open "id_file.txt" for reading\n);
my %idHash;
while (my $line = <ID_FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($key, $value) = split("/s+", $line);
    push(@{$idHash{$line}}, $value);
}
close ID_FILE;
```

The `@{$idHash{$line}}` is treating the hash value as a reference to a hash, you can separate it like this, if it's clearer:

```
open (ID_FILE, "id_file.txt")
    or die qq(Can't open "id_file.txt" for reading\n);
my %idHash;
while (my $line = <ID_FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($key, $value) = split("/s+", $line);
    my @tempList = \$idHash{$line};
    push(@tempList, $value);
}
close ID_FILE;
```

Now, when you do your lookup, you'll have to go through the list:

```
open (ID_LIST, 'list_of_ids.txt')
    or die qq(Can't open "list_of_ids.txt" for reading\n);
while (my $line = <ID_LIST>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @tempList = \$idHash{$line};
    print "The values for key $line are " . join(", ", @tempList) . "\n";;
    print "The values for key $line are " . join(", ", @{$idHash{$line}) . "\n"; 
}
```

Or, instead of doing a `join`, you could parse though the list item for each key:

```
open (ID_LIST, 'list_of_ids.txt')
    or die qq(Can't open "list_of_ids.txt" for reading\n);
while (my $line = <ID_LIST>) {
    chomp $line;
    foreach my $value (@{$idHash{$line}) {
        print qq(Value: $line" \t key "$value"\n);
    }
}
```

By the way, I am sorry, but I haven't tested the code due to a lack of time. Therefore, I can guarantee there are syntax errors and bugs all around. However, it does give you the general idea how you can use a Perl Hash to quickly pull up a value via a key, and how you can store multiple values for a single key.

It looks like the original Python answer suffered the same issue. However, the revised one looks correct.

Comment: I need to return both of them. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Okay, makes things a bit more complex. See my amended answer above.

Comment: I was writing it. Sorry. Took me a while to get it written. I should have modified my answer, then replied to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hash by reading the first file. Put your id as key and array of the corresponding set of values as value. While reading second file just do lookup in the hash you created by using first file.